# meeting properties are not preserved by outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

In a Outlook addin I want to set PS_INTERNET_HEADERS properties on outgoing emails/meeting requests. I can see that for meetings those properties are not preserved when I open the incoming meeting (I send it to myself) - the email header for my property does not exist and I cannot see the property in OutlookSpy. for regular emails (not meetings) properties are preserved fine.

I can also reproduce this behavior with OutlookSpy - I create a new meeting, in OutlookSpy I add a PS_INTERNET_HEADERS named property, and send the meeting to myself. when I open the incoming meeting the property is gone. (it also does not appear when I open the meeting from the SentItems)

Comment: Where and when do you set the PS_INTERNET_HEADERS property? What code exactly do you use?

Answer (score 0):

When and how do you set the properties? Keep in mind that `AppointmentItem` is never sent. When you call `AppointmentItem.Send`, a new `MeetingItem` object is created and sent. You can only access it in the `Application.ItemSend` event handler.

Comment: when the user clicks on a button I added to the "new meeting" window, I set the property (using HrSetOneProp with the PS_INTERNET_HEADERS guid). from what you say I understand that instead of setting the property at the time the user clicks on the button, I should rather remember it and upon ItemSend I should set the property on the sent item?

Comment: Correct. Check if the property was set on the AppointmentItem object in the Calendar folder (click IMessage in OutlookSpy). You can access the appointment (and that property) from the ItemSend event handler by calling MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment.